# JTA Timeout Seconds in WebLogic Scripting Tool

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

I want to use The WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST), the command-line scripting interface that system administrators and operators use to monitor and manage WebLogic Server instances and domains. 
I want to change the property JTA Timeout Seconds, I know that I can put the properties in a property file, e.g.

```
jdbc.datasource.0.pool.capacity.initial = 15
```

But I don't know the key in the property of the JTA Timeout Seconds.

[image]

Comment: I think you are using a custom solution based uppon WLST to update your domain's configuration. Out of the box, there is no wlst function which is based on a property file that can update any parameter in a domain. WLST uses JMX to access WLS MBeans and update their properties.

Comment: Command Options for WLST:  -loadProperties propertyFilename: use this option to load properties into the WLST session, where propertyFilename is the name of a file that contains name=value pairs.